# MYSQL Update only one key:value inside a json array

Tags: php, mysql, json

I need to be bale to reset just one value for one json key

```
{
"newsletter":"1",
"contactcategories":"40",
"newslettermessagetitle":"Hey hey its  the monkeys",
"newslettermessage":"And we got something to say...."
}
```

I'm trying to work out how i can format a MYSQL UPDATE query that will leave everything alone in that json but only change the 1 to 0 for the newsletter key.

So basically this ends up my result:

```
{
"newsletter":"0",
"contactcategories":"40",
"newslettermessagetitle":"Hey hey its  the monkeys",
"newslettermessage":"And we got something to say...."
}
```

I have this so far but cant wrap my head around it. Is it even possible to update only one json key and value using a mysql query?

```
UPDATE #__table 
SET params='(SELECT *
            FROM #__table
            WHERE params LIKE '%\"newsletter\":\"1\"%')'i WHERE id='$id'
```

Thanks to any one who can help :)
Jonny

Comment: mysql has no clue what json is, other than being text. don't manipulate json in mysql. pull the json string in your client, decode it, manipulate the object/array there, re-encode to json, then update the db.

Comment: As above, or normalize your database rather than dumping json into it

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question: decode the json string into an array:

```
$myResultArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

and then you can use the associative array.

For example: `$myResultArray['newsletter'];`

```
$sql = "UPDATE #__table SET newsletter = '".$myResultArray['newsletter']."' WHERE id='".$id."'";
```

Comment: Hi, but how do i update that back into the database?

Comment: Aha ok, thankyou.But where am i setting teh value of zero back in that update?

Comment: Thank you my Hungarian friend :), greetings from Australia. I will first try what you suggest and i think i will get it. Thanks for your help. You basically answered my question and even explained in practice what the other two fellows mentioned. Pull the json out then work with it then go back to the MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in a single query, as MySql has no concept of JSON.
You would instead need to make a select:

```
"SELECT params FROM #__table WHERE id='{$id}'"
```

edit the data in php

```
$params = json_decode($row['params']);
$params->newsletter = 0;
```

Then update

```
"UPDATE #__table SET params = '{json_encode($params)}' WHERE id='{$id}'"
```